# Awk indicating the first character not to be #

Tags: regex, awk, expression

Is there a way to specify the first character not to be something?
There are many ways to limit what it can be but I don't recall a way to say what it can't be.

for example if ! meant not to be

```
root 4

awk {/[!#][Rr][Oo][Oo][Tt]/{ }}
```

Comment: regex, not wildcard: `[^#]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol for "not" in a bracket expression is the caret (or "circumflex") `^`, but it *must be the first character* inside the brackets in order to have this meaning. The example given in the comments above is `[^#]`, which means one character that is not `#`. So the regular expression `/[^#]/` would match any string that does not have a `#` *anywhere* in it. This is not all of what you asked for:

> Is there a way to specify the **first character** not to be something?

One thing that makes regular expressions hard for some people to read is that many symbols have different meanings based on context. The caret `^` is also used to indicate the beginning of a line. With a regex in awk, you can specify that the first character on the line (the first thing after the beginning of the line `^`) is not a `#` with:

```bash
awk '/^[^#]/{ ... }'
```

This would execute the block of code `{ ... }` for every line of input that does *not* start with `#` at the beginning of the line. Note that this would, however, match a line that starts with other characters, and then has a `#` somewhere in it. `/^[^#]/` would also *not* match an empty line, since there is no character for `[^#]` to consume. As you can see, there are many nuances and subtleties to consider as you tailor your regex for your needs.  For more, look up [awk regex](https://www.google.com/#q=awk+regex), [POSIX regex](https://www.google.com/#q=posix+regex), or just type [`man -s7 regex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) in your terminal.